# Network Manager breaks manual routes

Tags: networking, 13.10, network-manager, routing

I have Ubuntu 13.10, Saucy Salamander x64 running as a guest in VirtualBox (with Windows 7 as a host).

I wrote this `/etc/network/interfaces` because I need to add a large number of permanent, manual static routes:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    up ip -force -b /etc/network/eth1-routes
```

`eth1-routes` contains several lines of the form:

```
route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 172.x.x.x dev eth1
```

where `172.x.x.x` is the gateway that VBox NAT gives me.

By running `netstat -nr` it appears that all of my manual routes have been successfully added, including routes to get to two DNS servers via `172.x.x.x`.

However, network manager says that both devices are "not managed". If I set `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` `managed=true`, network manager works again but my routes are lost. So my current compromise is to set `managed=false` and comment out the `eth0` lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Is there a way to have a device be managed and still do manual routes as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network Manager does not recognize the statements you wrote in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

So your can add your script `eth1-routes` as a dispatcher script for Network Manager in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`. It will be run every time an interface goes up. Maybe you have to write in your script an "if clause" to only add the routes if `eth1` comes up. Like this:

```
if [ "$IFACE" == "eth1" ]; then
  route add ...
  route add ...
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Network Manager manages its own static routes - open network manager and select "wired connection 1". Select edit. select IPv4 tab. At the bottom of this page is a button for "Routes". That is where you add them. When done NM writes to a file with root permissions in its /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ directory called "Wired connection 1"

Example follows

```
ls -l /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
total 4.0K
-rw------- 1 root root 216 Aug 26 10:38 Wired connection 1

sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired\ connection\ 1

[802-3-ethernet]
mac-address=A:Real:Mac:Add:re:ss

[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=df4491fc-0981-4071-82ae-04c7b2d6d9fc
type=802-3-ethernet

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=auto
route1=10.2.2.0/24,10.1.1.68,1
```

Where 10.2.2.0 is the destination network and 10.1.1.68 is the gateway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a route to Ubuntu that persists reboot and does not use the default interface as the gateway then you may want to add a route statement to the NetworkManager configuration file for the specific interface.

Add a route to the **/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/"connection name"** configuration file by adding the route statement to the configuration file for (assuming IPv4). The route has four parts; *"the first being the destination IPv4 network or address (network byte order), the second the destination network or address prefix (1 - 32), the third being the next-hop (network byte order) if any, and the fourth being the route metric"*.

```
[ipv4]
method=auto
route1=172.16.0.0/16,192.168.3.1,1
```

This is the equivalent of setting the route using the following route statement:

```
route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.3.1
```

The route keyname is defined in Table 12 in the NetmorkManager developer documentation. Please see the following URL for more information: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/0.9/ref-settings.html